# Calling Google Cloud function with arguments

Tags: function, google-cloud-functions, yaml

I have a function which fetch sql file from Cloud storage. This function accept project_id,bucket_id & sql_file

```
from google.cloud import storage    
def read_sql(request):
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    project_id=request_json['project_id']
    bucket_id=request_json['bucket_id']
    sql_file=request_json['sql_file']    
    gcs_client = storage.Client(project_id)
    bucket = gcs_client.get_bucket(bucket_id)
    blob = bucket.get_blob(sql_file)
    contents = blob.download_as_string()
    return contents.decode('utf-8')
```

It works fine when I test it with these parameters

```
{"project_id":"my_project","bucket_id":"my_bucket","sql_file":"daily_load.sql"}
```

I am trying to call this function in Google WorkFlow but don't know how to setup arguments in call http.get

```
main:
  params: []
  steps:
  - init:
      assign:
      - project: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID")}
      - location: "us-central1"
      - name: "workflow_test_return_sql1"
      - service_account: "sa@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"  # Use App Engine default SA.
    - get_function:
      call: googleapis.cloudfunctions.v1.projects.locations.functions.get
      args:
        name: ${"projects/" + project + "/locations/" + location + "/functions/" + name}
      result: function
  - grant_permission_to_all:
      call: googleapis.cloudfunctions.v1.projects.locations.functions.setIamPolicy
      args:
        resource: ${"projects/" + project + "/locations/" + location + "/functions/" + name}
        body:
          policy:
            bindings:
            - members: ["allUsers"]
              role: "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
  - call_function:
      call: http.get
      args:
        url: ${function.httpsTrigger.url}
      result: resp
```

Code written in Workflow is yaml

Any idea how to build function call URL with arguments ?

I have tried below two approached but they didn't work

```
- call_function:
      call: http.post
      args: 
        url: ${function.httpsTrigger.url}
        body:
            input: {"project_id":"my_project","bucket_id":"my_bucket","sql_file":"daily_load.sql"}
      result: resp
```

and

```
- call_function:
      call: http.get
      args: 
        url: ${function.httpsTrigger.url}?project_id=my_project?bucket_id=my_bucket?sql_file=daily_load.sql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close!! Try that

```
- call_function:
      call: http.get
      args: 
        url: ${function.httpsTrigger.url + "?project_id=" + my_project + "&bucket_id=" + my_bucket + "&sql_file=" + daily_load.sql}
```

---

**EDIT 1**

Here the post option with JSON body (note that YAML and JSON are similar. here how to write your JSON with yaml)

```
- call_function:
      call: http.post
      args: 
        url: ${function.httpsTrigger.url}
        body:
          project_id: "my_project"
          bucket_id: "my_bucket"
          sql_file: "daily_load.sql"
      result: resp
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That didn't work. I am receiving code 500 & logs are not giving any indication of whats wrong ?


`"body": "Error: could not handle the request\n",
"message": "HTTP server responded with error code 500"`

Comment: Cloud Workflow invocation work, but your Cloud Functions fail. Adapt the Cloud function to read data either from GET parameter or from body parameter. I updated my answer with the POST option

Comment: From the tests I’ve made, I am convinced that [invoking the Cloud Function as an HTTP endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/http-requests#invoke-endpoint) and sending the parameters through the body would work, as the Cloud Function is expecting an JSON rather than a query string, that's why it gives a 500 error code when you send them in that way.